# How to provide option object for main yarn files?

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg, bower

I have migrated a project from Bower and NPM to Yarn. When implementing the `mainYarnFiles` library (previous incarnation of the project used `mainBowerFiles`) this code (executed in `gulp.js`):

```
var yarnOptions = {
    path: {
        checkExistence: true,
        modulesFolder: '../node_modules/@bower_components',
        jsonFile: '../package.json'
    }
}

console.log(mainYarnFiles(yarnOptions))
```

Throws this error:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:125:11)
    at Object.resolve (path.js:161:7)
```

I believe this is because I have not correctly populated the `yarnOptions` object (above). Is this correct or have I got something wrong with the packages I'm trying to reference?

This is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "project description",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "Project"
  ],
  "author": "Me",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "del": "^2.2.2",
    "eslint-config-angular": "^0.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-angular": "^1.5.0",
    "file-saver": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-angular-filesort": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp-angular-templatecache": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.1",
    "gulp-cheerio": "^0.6.2",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^2.2.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-eslint": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-filter": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-flatten": "^0.3.1",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-if": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp-inject": "^4.1.0",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-rev": "^7.1.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.9.1",
    "gulp-string-replace": "^0.3.1",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "natives": "^1.1.6",
    "require-dir": "^0.3.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "stream-series": "^0.1.1",
    "uglify-save-license": "^0.4.1",
    "yargs": "^6.5.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@bower_components/angular": "angular/bower-angular#1.6.0",
    "@bower_components/angular-animate": "angular/bower-angular-animate#1.6.0",
    "@bower_components/angular-bootstrap": "angular-ui/bootstrap-bower#2.5.0",
    "@bower_components/angular-bootstrap-slider": "seiyria/angular-bootstrap-slider#^0.1.28",
    "@bower_components/angular-cache": "jmdobry/angular-cache#^4.6.0",
    "@bower_components/angular-confirm-modal": "Schlogen/angular-confirm#^1.2.6",
    "@bower_components/angular-dynamic-locale": "lgalfaso/angular-dynamic-locale#0.1.32",
    "@bower_components/angular-i18n": "angular/bower-angular-i18n#1.6.0",
    "@bower_components/angular-moment": "urish/angular-moment#^1.0.1",
    "@bower_components/angular-translate": "PascalPrecht/bower-angular-translate#2.13.1",
    "@bower_components/angular-translate-loader-url": "PascalPrecht/bower-angular-translate-loader-url#2.13.1",
    "@bower_components/angular-ui-router": "angular-ui/angular-ui-router-bower#^0.4.2",
    "@bower_components/angular-ui-router-uib-modal": "nonplus/angular-ui-router-uib-modal#^0.0.11",
    "@bower_components/angular-ui-validate": "angular-ui/ui-validate#^1.2.2",
    "@bower_components/c3": "masayuki0812/c3#0.4.11",
    "@bower_components/d3": "mbostock-bower/d3-bower#3.5.17",
    "@bower_components/lodash": "lodash/lodash#^4.17.4",
    "@bower_components/moment": "moment/moment#^2.29.3",
    "@bower_components/seiyria-bootstrap-slider": "seiyria/bootstrap-slider#^11.0.2",
    "bower": "^1.8.4",
    "bower-away": "^1.1.2",
    "main-yarn-files": "^3.0.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "yarn": ">= 1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was correct: the options object contained `path` instead of `path` (as described in [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/main-yarn-files#paths)) and needed paths correcting:

```
const yarnOptions = {
    paths: {
        checkExistence: true,
        modulesFolder: 'node_modules/@bower_components',
        jsonFile: 'package.json'
    }
}
```